# Flutter Promise with modal Loading animation while async task

Tags: flutter

I am doing a async API call to fetch some data before navigating to the next screen. This works fine, but within this API call the user could edit the current screen. I want to show some loading animation modal while the async task is beeing active. Is there a way to do this by using the Promise functionality?

```dart
_apiCall(...).then((retVal) {

    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(retVal)));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a workaround for that:

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: isLoading ? getLoadingBar() : ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ...,
        ...,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

Widget getLoadingBar() {
  return new Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Center(
      child: Loading(indicator: BallPulseIndicator(), size: 100.0),
    ),
  );
}
```

inside my RaisedButton:

```
onPressed: () {
  setState() {
    isLoading = true;
  }

  _apiCall(...).then((retVal) {

    setState() {
      isLoading = false;
    }

    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(retVal)));

  });

}
```